# vue+django+graphql:has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django, vue.js, graphql

the question is 'has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.'

I use Django+Graphql and I can get the data through postman。
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQuPf.png)

In order to solve the cross domain problem of Django, I have done the following work

1.install django-cors-headers

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

2.Add “corsheaders” to the list of installed apps in the settings.py file

3.Add CORS_ALLOW_METHODS and CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS

But in the front end of Vue, cross domain problems are encountered
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RqqU.png)

my django logs：

```
[31/Jan/2021 04:42:27] "OPTIONS /graphql HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

Here is my configuration

django/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('graphql/', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True)),
    path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
]
```

django/setting.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '08ux)8987i4d#7^@4a-e3y601*rwhl)zdpl=5#te4f8#!eh(_5'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # app
    'company',
    # graphql
    'graphene_django',
    # cors
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'graphQL_demo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'graphQL_demo.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'graphQL_demo.schema.schema'
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
#     'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
# )

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

Request content written in Vue

vue/comp.vue

```
<template>
  <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            id="navbarDropdown"
            role="button"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link disabled"
            href="#"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-disabled="true"
            >Disabled</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </nav> -->
  <div>
    <table class="table table-striped mt-4">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">name</th>
        <th scope="col">title</th>
        <th scope="col">city</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr v-for="input in directory.edges" :key="input.id">
        <td>{{ input.node.employeeName }}</td>
        <td>{{ input.node.employeeTitle.titleName }}</td>
        <td>{{ input.node.employeeCity.cityName }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'CompanyData',
  data () {
    return {
      directory: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      var result = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql",
        data: {
          query: `
                {
                  employees {
                  edges {
                  node {
                      id
                      employeeName
                      employeeTitle {
                        titleName
                      }
                      employeeCity {
                        cityName
                      }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            `,
        },
      });
      this.directory = result.data.data.allEmployees;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you may have configured your Django app to append a slash `/` to paths that do not end in a slash. Try adding a slash to the end of your URL?: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/`

Comment: In your `settings.py` try adding `"*"` in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.

Comment: @Mubasharjaved I added allowed_ Hosts = ['*'] in setting.py and restart it ，But it didn't work .In case of cross domain problems, do Django and Vue need to be configured. Or just configure it at one end

Comment: @IainShelvington i try adding  a slash to the end of URL in comp.vue `url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/"` and the django  log shows `Method Not Allowed: /graphql/
[31/Jan/2021 04:46:57] "OPTIONS /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 405 71`

Comment: You need to add `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE` setting